# Android Database last updated

Tags: android, database, version-control

I was wondering whether there is a way to check when the database was last updated?

I'm currently checking to see if the database exists at the moment - if so, dont update, but i was wondering to see if, for example it has been 7 days since the last update - then update.

```
private boolean checkDataBase()
{
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
    try
    {
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_FULL_PATH, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        checkDB.close();
    } 
    catch (SQLiteException e) 
    {
        // database doesn't exist yet.
    }
        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}
```

Any suggestions or tutorials would be appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you update the database you could save a `long` value to `SharedPreferences` that represents the time of update using `System.currentTimeMillis()` for example.

Next time you want to check if an update is required simply retrieve the last update time and compare with `System.currentTimeMillis()` to see if the difference is greater than 7 days.

Comment: You could also store this value in the database itself in a separate table (ie: updates).  This has the added benefit of letting you keep an audit trail of when the database was updated, in case you ever need it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about such method to check it, but you can save the date each time you update the database, and check against it.

A convenient place to store it will be [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

Comment: Ya i haven't seen anything like it myself, i'l probably just go ahead with checking a version control variable on the database like time as you suggested.

Thanks